# Heatsink selection and datasheet specifications for Thermoelectric Generator

Tags: datasheet, heat, heatsink, peltier

I have bought [this](https://www.acdcshop.gr/content/PM-50X50-150_DTE.pdf) TEG. I am planning to use it **as a generator**, for energy harvesting applications.

I am having trouble though understanding both the diagrams and the meaning of the TEG's specifications in the datasheet. To be specific, how can I use the info provided in the datasheet to determine for example, what **heatsink** would be required for the TEG, while having a **DT=20** degrees, and also what would its **output power, voltage, current** be at that DT ?

Comment: start here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=TEG

Comment: That spec sheet is aimed at using it as a cooler, not a generator. I don't think you can infer its generator performance from that, but you might be able to find better datasheet for a similar model. Short answer is : try it, but don't expect much.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 It is the first place I looked, but most of the posts talk about using TEG as a cooler, and others have specifications that I do not for my device.

Comment: What have you done to find out how these modules work as generators? And what sort of power level would meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That spec sheet is aimed at using it as a cooler, not a generator. I don't think you can infer its generator performance from that, but you might be able to find better datasheet for a similar model. Short answer is : try it, but don't expect much.

[This](https://thermoelectric-generator.com/thermoelectric-lower-temperature-power-module-selections/) is about the best datasheet I have found : scroll down to TEG2-126LDT. (Available from that site; follow the links for more data).

> Th=40, Tc=30C, Voltage at match load 0.2V, Amps at match load: 0.045A, Match load 4.5Ω
> Th=60, Tc=30C, Voltage at match load 0.6V, Amps at match load: 0.11A, Match load 5.2Ω

So, at dT = 10C, you can expect 9 mW, and at dT = 30C you can expect about 66 mW, both into loads about 5 ohms. At 20C you'll get somewhere between these values using their module. They chose it for this role; yours may offer a bit less.

As for the heatsink required : it is whatever you need to maintain that temperature difference. The [full datasheet](https://thermoelectric-generator.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/TEG2-126LDT-Spec.-sheet.1.-REV..pdf) shows heat flow across the module as 52W, but that's with a dT of 170C. You can expect heat flow to scale nearly linearly with dT, so I would suggest designing the heatsink to allow for at least 10W at 20C or 5W at 10C.

Now you have a hot source at T2 and a cold source (presumably air, since you mention a heatsink) at T1, and a dT (total) of T2 - T1. Some of that will be dissipated across the heatsink - dT(sink) - leaving dT(TEG) to generate power.

dT(TEG) = dT(total) - dT(sink).

Then for example, if you have a 45C heat source and 25C air temperature (dT(Total) = 20C), and you need 9 mW so dT(TEG) = 10C, then dT(Sink) = 10C and dissipation is 5W. So you need a 10C/5W heatsink = 2C/Watt.

Or for 66 mW, you need dT(TEG) = 30C, choose a heatsink to dissipate 15W at 1C/Watt giving dT(Sink) = 15C. If your air temp is 25C you need a heat source at 25C + 15C (heatsink) + 30C (TEG) = 70C.